# vim :grep using the bash 'globstar' option

Tags: bash, grep, vim

I am (slowly) switching to Vim for everyday Ruby on Rails coding (Linux Cinnamon 64bit). Being a newbie, I recently came across something I don't understand.

I want to use the :vimgrep and :grep commands for searching a pattern in a file tree from Vim. I am able to do so without problems with the :vimgrep command:

```
:vimgrep /User/gj **/*.rb
```

However, when I try to use the same command with :grep (which should use the system grep), no result is returned:

```
:grep User **/*.rb
```

Googling around, I found that the **globstar** options of my bash shell was not enabled:

```
$shopt globstar
globstar        off
```

It was easy to turn on:

```
$shopt -s globstar
```

I added the above line to my .vimrc file, and I made sure the option was permanently enabled in my bash.

With the new option, I could execute grep this way and get the desired results:

```
$grep User **/*.rb
```

Unfortunately, the :grep command from inside Vim is still not working with the '**'. And executing:

```
!shopt globstar
```

from inside Vim, the result is still **off**.

So the question is: can I propagate my bash's **globstar** option to my Vim external command environment? Otherwise, can I somehow set my **grepprg** option in Vim in a way that will allow me to use the globstar properly?

Thanks in advance to anyone who will help

Comment: Which version of `vim`? What does `:help starstar-wildcard` say?

Comment: `:set shell=/bin/zsh` or `:set shell=/bin/bash\ -O\ globstar`, or `:let $BASHOPTS="globstar"`

Comment: vim version is **VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)**, I think the `:help starstar-wildcard` is relative to the internal commands (correct me if I am wrong) as the `**` was already working with `:vimgrep`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell options don't inherit to forked shells, but that's what Vim does when you use the `:!` command: it launches a new shell.

You can influence those forked shells in Vim via the `'shell'` option:

```
:set shell+=\ -O\ globstar
```

or

```
:set shell=/bin/bash\ -O\ globstar
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. I also added `set shell+=\ -O\ globstar` to my .vimrc. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks; glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!